# trocando de um entry para o outro quando digitar uma palavra

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Gente, me ajude com isso, tenho dois entry e preciso que quando eu digitar uma palavra por exemplo (Python) ele mude de um entry para o outro automaticamente

```
from tkinter import * 

janela2.geometry('250x250+100+100')

lb2 = Label(janela2, text='coloque seu nome')

barrinha= Entry(janela2)

barrinha.place(x=80,y=80)

barrinha1= Entry(janela2)

barrinha1.place(x=80,y=120)

janela2.mainloop ()
```

Comment: Use a formatação para código

Comment: pode dar um exemplo ?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer seu programa reconhecer que terminou de digitar a palavra com um toque na tecla <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Então o código ficaria assim:

```
from tkinter import *

def muda_barrinha(tecla):
    barrinha1.focus()

janela2 = Tk()
janela2.geometry('250x250+100+100')

lb2 = Label(janela2, text='coloque seu nome')

barrinha = Entry(janela2)

barrinha.place(x=80, y=80)
barrinha.focus()
barrinha.bind("<Return>", muda_barrinha)
```

O método `bind` pega o evento tecla enter (Return) e chama a função `muda_barrinha`:

```
barrinha1 = Entry(janela2)
barrinha1.place(x=80, y=120)

janela2.mainloop()
```